# What is the best way to receive back (to Fragment) data from DialogFragment

Tags: android

I'm fighting couple of days with a such simple think like receiving back a data from a `DialogFragment`. First I tried to make a `DialogFragment` as a nested class, but it happened it fails on orientation change. Then I decided to user `interfaces` passing a `listener` to a `DialogFragment`, but here is a problem on how to persist the `listener` after `orientation change`. Then someone from here suggested to use `setTargetFragment()`, but it is also doesn't work because of a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17423#c1).

It is such a common task, how you guys get data back from `DialogFragment`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using interfaces is definitely the best way.
In your `DialogFragment`, register the listener in `onAttach(Activity)` and you will be able to receive your callback even after an orientation change.

Comment: All my app logic is in `Fragment`, not `Activity`. Do you mean I can have a method in `Activity` where I can retrieve my `Fragment` and execute needed method of it?

Comment: Exactly. You should use your `Activity` to "forward" your data to the `Fragment` you want.
As far as I know, there is no other way to communicate between `Fragment`s than to go through `Activity`.

Answer (score 5):

Using interfaces, and hooking up in `onAttach(Activity)` definitely works, and [the example given by Google](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) suggest to communicate between components this way, but there is definitely a better way to do things. [Square](https://squareup.com/) came out with a nice solution that you can find here:

http://corner.squareup.com/2012/07/otto.html

It's an event bus that you can register with to receive event notifications, and really decouples your component communication code.

To register for an event from your DialogFragment (say, you've got the data you need and you're about to dismiss, so your event notifies all interested parties with the data) all you'd do in your Activity is:

```
bus.register(this);
```

Then in the same Activity you'd have something like:

```
@Subscribe
public void dataChanged(DataChangedEvent event) {
    // TODO React to data.
}
```

Then the DialogFragment, would only need to call something like:

```
bus.post(new DataChangedEvent(/*your data here*/));
```

and your Activity would be notified. No coupling of your Activities to your Fragments, and no keeping track of listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you attach the logic activity to the fragment manager be sure to use the additional parameter for tag. Then, in `onCreate` of your DialogFragment just call `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("parent fragment");` to get a reference to the parent.